# Out Of Memory GroundOverlay Map Android

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap, out-of-memory, gmsgroundoverlay

I have a problem !

I have add a GraundOverlay on Map with this code:

```
final LatLng NEWARK = new LatLng(40.775067, 14.789154);
    final GroundOverlayOptions auleP = new GroundOverlayOptions();
    auleP.image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.piano0p))
            .transparency(0.7f)
            .bearing(60)
            .position(NEWARK, 38f, 38f);

    over = mMap.addGroundOverlay(auleP);
```

This code in Android KitKat work whitout problem but if I run this on Android Lollipop chash whit OutOfMemory error that can see in this Logcat

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 16777228 byte allocation with 2655368 free bytes and 2MB until OOM 
11-03 14:30:30.771 30020-30093/uninsideproject.com.uninside2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
11-03 14:30:30.771 30020-30093/uninsideproject.com.uninside2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
11-03 14:30:30.771 30020-30093/uninsideproject.com.uninside2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:831)
11-03 14:30:30.771 30020-30093/uninsideproject.com.uninside2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:808)
11-03 14:30:30.771 30020-30093/uninsideproject.com.uninside2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:775)
11-03 14:30:30.771 30020-30093/uninsideproject.com.uninside2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.c.i.a(Unknown Source)
11-03 14:30:30.771 30020-30093/uninsideproject.com.uninside2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.c.l.a(Unknown Source)
11-03 14:30:30.771 30020-30093/uninsideproject.com.uninside2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.c.l.a(Unknown Source)
11-03 14:30:30.771 30020-30093/uninsideproject.com.uninside2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.j.a(Unknown Source)
11-03 14:30:30.771 30020-30093/uninsideproject.com.uninside2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.r.a(Unknown Source)
11-03 14:30:30.771 30020-30093/uninsideproject.com.uninside2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.l.a(Unknown Source)
11-03 14:30:30.771 30020-30093/uninsideproject.com.uninside2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.l.b(Unknown Source)
11-03 14:30:30.771 30020-30093/uninsideproject.com.uninside2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.cj.g(Unknown Source)
11-03 14:30:30.771 30020-30093/uninsideproject.com.uninside2 E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.n.cj.run(Unknown Source)`
```

In What way I can resolve this?

Help me, please

Comment: use android:largeHeap="true" under the application tag of your manifest file, might solve your problem.

Comment: But isn't a clear way because risk a overflow bug

Comment: Do you have one resource for each resolution (mdpi. hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi)? What is the size (in pixels) of your `R.drawable.piano0p` resource for each resolution?

Comment: Antonio I've a sigle resorce in drawable folder, the size of image is 600x650 pixel

Comment: @Alberto what devices are you testing your app into? Are there other `GroundOverlay`s in your map?